# MySQL JOIN WHERE forgein Key = id1 AND forgein Key = id2

Tags: mysql, join

I am having a bit of a brain block with this problem and I am finding it hard to search for a solution because I cant phrase the question correctly to bring up the relevant information.

I am trying to get back "fProduct" record from the table below where it has a "fAttribute" 
of 2 and 20.

```
id  fAttribute  fProduct
19      2        2967
48      2        2923
50      2        3008
51      20       3008
52      2        2295
53      20       2295
```

My statment below produces 0 results when I would expect to return fProduct's 2295 and 3008.

```
SELECT fProduct 
FROM  tableName 
WHERE fAttribute = 2 AND fAttribute = 20
GROUP BY fProduct
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use INNER JOINS or use EXISTS conditions:

INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.fProduct
FROM MyTable a
     INNER JOIN MyTable b ON a.fProduct = b.fProduct AND b.fAttribute = 2
     INNER JOIN MyTable c ON a.fProduct = c.fProduct AND c.fAttribute = 20
```

EXISTS:

```
SELECT afproduct
FROM MyTable a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT b.id FROM MyTable b WHERE a.fProduct = b.fProduct AND b.fAttribute = 2)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT c.id FROM MyTable c WHERE a.fProduct = c.fProduct AND c.fAttribute = 20)
```

Comment: Wicked I used the "Inner join" option in the end. Cheers top one dude.

Answer (score 1):

A join should help:

```
SELECT distinct a.fProduct 
FROM  tableName as a
join tableName as b on b.product = a.product
WHERE a.fAttribute = 2 and  b.fAttribute = 20
```

Comment: You're missing `= 2` before the `and` in your where clause

Answer (score 0):

Since your are already doing a `GROUP BY` just change your `WHERE` clause to an `OR` or an IN and add the  `HAVING COUNT(fattribute) = 2` which makes sure it has both.

```
SELECT fproduct 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  fattribute IN (2 , 20)
GROUP  BY fproduct 
HAVING COUNT(fattribute) = 2
```